# Connect new git branch with new local folder

Tags: git

I have copied a local folder A to another folder B. A is connected to GIT via branch **BRANCH-A**.

Now I have created another branch which is **BRANCH-B**. Now I want that folder B connects with BRANCH-B.

The folders A & B both have .git sub folder where I can see the config file. I have edited the config file of folder B to add the new branch

```
[branch "BRANCH-B"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/BRANCH-B
```

But when I go to the folder B and issue the command --

git branch -a

It still shows the **BRANCH-A**. Also how can push **BRANCH-A** to **BRANCH-B** and connect **BRANCH-B** with the local folder B?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is very confusing. Could you use your actual branch names? `git branch -a` is not going to work, even if your branch was called `a`.

Comment: I issued `git branch` and it gives me BRANCH-A which is not correct.

Comment: `git branch` tells you which branch you’re on. `git checkout [branch name]` will switch to that branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a branch to your git configuration does not create the branch.

To create a branch `BRANCH-B` based on `BRANCH-A`, you can do:

```
repo-B$ git checkout BRANCH-A -b BRANCH-B
```

Then, to create BRANCH-B on the remote and to set it as the upstream branch:

```
repo-B$ git push -u origin BRANCH-B
```

Note that it is not necessary to create a separate folder for each branch. However, if you want to checkout a branch into a separate folder, it can be easier and faster to use `git worktree`. The following command creates a copy of BRANCH-A named BRANCH-B and does a checkout of it into a new folder `../repo-B`:

```
repo-A$ git worktree add -b BRANCH-B ../repo-B BRANCH-A
```